# undefined method `booking_items' for #<MeetingRoom:0x0000557526c2b9b0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, serialization

I was trying to show the availability of space in the show space API. The logic behind the code is availability = total available space count - total booked space count. Can someone please help me to code this because am new to rails API

My Space Controller

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

# Spaces controller
class Api::V1::SpacesController < ApiController
  before_action :fetch_space, only: [:show]

  def index
    spaces = Space.all
    render_collection(spaces, { name: 'spaces' }, each_serializer: SpaceShortSerializer)
  end

  def show
    render json: @space, serializer: SpaceSerializer
  end

  def create
    if space = current_user.spaces.create(space_params)
      render_object(space, { name: 'space' }, { serializer: SpaceSerializer })
    else
      render_error(space.errors.full_messages)
    end
  end


  private

  def fetch_space
    space_id = params[:space_id] || params[:id]
    @space = Space.find(space_id)
  end

  def space_params
    params.require(:space).permit(:name, :email, :website, :phone,
                                  amenities_attributes: [:id, :name, :available],
                                  meeting_rooms_attributes: [:id, :count, :capacity, pricings_attributes: [:id, :duration, :price]],
                                  private_offices_attributes: [:id, :count, :capacity, pricings_attributes: [:id, :duration, :price]],
                                  desks_attributes: [:id, :count, :desk_type, pricings_attributes: [:id, :duration, :price]],
                                  operating_hours_attributes: [:id, :day, :slot])
  end
end
```

Booking Controller

```
class Api::V1::BookingsController < ApiController
  before_action :fetch_space, only: [:show]

  def index
    bookings = Booking.all
    render_collection(bookings, { name: 'bookings' }, each_serializer: BookingItemSerializer )
  end
# booking_item_params: params[:entity_type]
  def create
    if booking = current_user.bookings.create(booking_params)
      render_object(booking, { name: 'booking' }, { serializer: BookingSerializer })
    else
      render_error(booking.errors.full_messages)
    end
  end

  private


  def booking_params
    params.require(:booking).permit(:space_id,
      booking_items_attributes: [:id, :entity_type, :entity_id, :count],
      booking_dates_attributes: [:id, :from_date, :to_date, :from_time, :to_time])
    end
  end
```

space serializer

```
class SpaceSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :email, :website, :phone, :owner, :available_amenities, :photos

  belongs_to :owner, except: :profile, serializer: OwnerSerializer

  has_many :meeting_rooms, serializer: MeetingRoomSerializer
  has_many :private_offices, serializer: PrivateOfficeSerializer
  has_many :desks, serializer: DeskSerializer
  has_many :operating_hours, serializer: OperatingHourSerializer

  def photos
    Photo::DUMMY_SPACE_IMAGES.shuffle.first(3)
  end
end
```

Booking Serializer

```
class BookingSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :user_id, :space_id, :status, :booked
  has_many :booking_items, serializer: BookingItemSerializer

  def booked
    object.booking_items.sum(:count)
  end
end
```

Booking Item serializer

```
class BookingItemSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

  has_many :meeting_rooms, serializer: MeetingRoomSerializer
  has_many :private_offices, serializer: PrivateOfficeSerializer
  has_many :desks, serializer: DeskSerializer
  has_many :operating_hours, serializer: OperatingHourSerializer


end
```

Meeting Room serializer

```
class MeetingRoomSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :count, :capacity, :availabitity, :photos
  belongs_to :booking_items, serializer: BookingItemSerializer

  def photos
    Photo::DUMMY_MEETING_ROOM_IMAGES.shuffle.first(2)
  end

  def availabitity
    object.count - object.booking_items.sum(:count)
  end
end
```

Like in meeting room serializer i need to show availability in private office and desk serializer too.

private office serializer

```
class PrivateOfficeSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :count, :capacity, :photos

  def photos
    Photo::DUMMY_PRIVATE_OFFICE_IMAGES.shuffle.first(2)
  end
end
```

desk serializer

```
class DeskSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :count, :desk_type, :photos


  def photos
    Photo::DUMMY_DESK_IMAGES.shuffle.first(2)
  end


end
```

Error Stack

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 150ms (ActiveRecord: 28.3ms | Allocations: 46623)



NoMethodError (undefined method `booking_items' for #<MeetingRoom:0x0000557526c2b9b0>):

app/serializers/meeting_room_serializer.rb:10:in `availabitity'
app/controllers/api/v1/spaces_controller.rb:13:in `show'
```

Comment: Can you add full error stack?

Comment: @Pavan NoMethodError in Api::V1::SpacesController#show
undefined method `booking_items' for #<MeetingRoom:0x0000557526c2b9b0>
Extracted source (around line #10):
8
9
10
11
12
              

  def availabitity
    object.count - object.booking_items.sum(:count)
  end
end

Comment: @Vishal am not asking logic am just asking about error and to make it more easier I just shared the logic behind this

Comment: @techiemaster Where is availability defined? Add details and full error stack

Comment: @RajdeepSingh added now can you please help me to solve it

Comment: What is the association between booking_items and meeting_room?

Comment: @techiemaster did you define the association right in the model?

Comment: booking items has many entity types. but I dont know how to link them. Like meeting room, desk and pivate offices

Comment: Actually the error is in availability method. I tried giving self.count and also tried object dot is their any method to call count which is a db field and availability  is a method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `MeetingRoomSerializer`

Change this line

```
belongs_to :booking_items, serializer: BookingItemSerializer
```

to

```
has_many :booking_items, serializer: BookingItemSerializer
```